# Add a link in management menu for specific role

Tags: routes

I can't find the way to display a link in the management menu for specific roles. The link shows up only for administrator, despite all the access callbacks I tried.

In the view displayed by the page callback I declared same path, menu  and access callbacks. As I don't know who is called last between module code and the view (?), I also tried with no menu nor access settings in the view.

If you could have a look at my implementation to check where I'm wrong ? Thanks a lot

```
function vts_dashboard_menu() {

  $items['admin/backoffice/production'] = array(
    'title' => 'Production',
    'description' => 'Edit catalogue',
    'page callback' => 'vts_dashboard_backoff_circuits',
    'access callback' => 'vts_dashboard_user_has_role',   
    'access arguments' =>  array('éditeur voyages', 'éditeur taxonomie', 'administrator'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'management',

    //2 alternative tests below. EVEN WITH TRUE, doesn't show up for non admin
    //'access callback' => TRUE,
    //OR ...
    //'access callback' => 'node_access',
    //'access arguments' => array('view', 1),
  );

  $items['admin/backoffice/production/circuits'] = array(
    'title' => 'Circuits',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10,
    'access callback' => 'vts_dashboard_user_has_role',   
    'access arguments' =>  array('éditeur voyages', 'administrator'),
  );
  // ... more items...
);
//page callback function
function vts_dashboard_backoff_circuits(){
  $viewname = 'circuits_vts'; 
  $viewdisplay = 'backoffice_products_list';
  return views_embed_view($viewname, $viewdisplay);
}
//access callback function
function vts_dashboard_user_has_role() { 
  global $user;
  $roles = func_get_args();
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE; 
}
```

**Precision** : these roles can see the pages/tabs called if they access directly to the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me ! The solution relied of course in a single line of my code, shared below in case it could help somebody.

I aimed to block many admin pages access, from which the `admin` path, in  a radical manner :

```
function vts_dashboard_menu_alter(&$items) {
   $items['admin']['access callback'] = 'vts_dashboard_admin_access_only';
  //more items ...  
}
function vts_dashboard_admin_access_only() {
  global $user;
  if( !in_array('administrator', $user->roles)){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

But `$items['admin']['access callback']` blocks also descendant menus items... commented out and all's fine again !

Be what it is, if any enlightened Drupal guru can tell me how to restrict access to `foo` path but no `foo/bar`, he'll receive all my consideration !